# How can I add a different menu to the mobile version of my bootstrap theme in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have a main menu for desktop and tablet but I want the links in that menu to change when the user gets to the mobile view. Not really sure where to start. This is what I did for the Bootstrap menu for my desktop version in my header.php file:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>"<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/snaglogo.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">


<?php
    $args = array(
          'menu'         => 'header-menu',
          'menu_class'   =>'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
          'container'    =>'false'
          );
            wp_nav_menu( $args );

 ?>

</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Am I adding another piece for mobile? Not really sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest on your navbar using the bootstrap class:

```
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
```

Then creating a separate navbar for mobile with the classes:

```
<div class="visible-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
```

This will allow you to set the links to something completely different, without effecting the navbar in an adverse way.

Here is more information about the "hidden" and "visible" classes:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: Ok I can do that. How would I get to alternate nav added in though? Would I make the second nav within the wordpress menu component?

Comment: Yes, it should be in the header.php file for the theme you are using.

Comment: @Bs3kg Instead of a separate <nav>, I added a separate <ul> inside one <nav>.  Not a big change, but seemed like a better solution for my case with less repeated markup (e.g. navbar-header).

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are looking to separate the mobile phone screen(the one with the button) and the normal bar only, use these classes:

**Button based menu:**

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
```

**Regular menu bar:**

```
<div class="visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 offers utilities to hide or add menu items for specific breakpoints. In my case I had to add some menu items in mobile view that are part of a secondary navigation in the desktop view (which disappears on mobile view). So for adding menu items only on screens that are below the lg breakpoint add the d-lg-none class (example is using React syntax):

```
<li className="nav-item d-lg-none">
   <Link to="/dashboard" className="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
      Dashboard
   </Link>
</li>
```

More information can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap 4 Hide Element Based On Screen Size

.hidden-* class (Bootstrap 4 Alpha) and .visible-* (Bootstrap 3) is removed.

You need to use display property, mainly d-*-none (hide) and d-*-block or d-*-inline-block (show).

If you want an element to hide on size sm and below, but visible on md, lg and xl, use d-none d-md-block.

```
        s (<576px)  sm (≥576px)     md (≥768px)     lg (≥992px)     xl (≥1200px)
```

d-none d-sm-block   hide    show          show              show         show
d-none d-md-block   hide    hide          show              show         show
d-none d-lg-block   hide    hide          hide               show        show
d-none d-xl-block   hide    hide          hide               hide        show
d-block d-xl-none   show    show          show             show          hide
d-block d-lg-none   show    show            show             hide        hide
d-block d-md-none   show    show            hide             hide        hide
d-block d-sm-none   show    hide            hide             hide        hide

[enter link description here](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/bootstrap/bootstrap-hide-element-based-on-viewport-size/)