# How to have seperate navbar for mobile and pc?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a portfolio and I wanted to have a seperate the navbar that appears in the mobile view and in the pc view. I want it in such a way that the mobile view is not fixed (meaning if I scrolldown it disappears), but i want the pc version to be fixed on the top of the page. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Thanks for the help :). Below are my HTML and CSS files:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.shalaj {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.nav-item {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <title>Exmaplea</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Example</a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="work.html">WORK</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="resume.html">RESUME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-4">Hi, I'm Name!</h1>
      <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <hr class="my-4">
      <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if it's only an HTML page, then yes, you have to add it every time. Second, since you have bootstrap included, look up media-queries, which are responsible for this kind of display you are trying for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat of a complicated problem depending on how thorough you want to be here. But basically, you need to look at [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). They allow you to specify *conditional* CSS to be used based on the properties of the client's device.

The most common use case it to specify a width of viewport (window or screen) under which the CSS should be different:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  //css to make the nav bar not fixed
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

in the above example, the `background-color` property will only be applied to the body **if** the window displaying your website is narrower than `800px`.

When you use this kind of media-query, you should also tell the browser *not to try and be smart*, because most browsers try to automatically optimise "desktop" sites to look good on mobile. With the following line, you can tell it "don't do anything, I've got this covered":

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

---

*PS:* In your post, you're asking about serving a different HTML or CSS file based on whether the client is browsing on mobile or desktop. This is a route we try and avoid for many reasons:

- it would require basing this decision on the *user agent* (basically a string identifying the browser) and this is not reliable and subject to changes
- it would necessitate a lot of code duplication as most of your code would be identical on both types of devices
- it does not allow you to make a website "responsive", i.e., that adapts to the changes required by the device (both mobile and desktop can change the size of the window, have different input capabilities...)

Answer (score -1):

Create separate navbar with bootstrap classes:

```
.hidden-xs, .hidden-sm, .hidden-md, .hidden-lg
```

Ex:
1. For mobile devices, following div can be used:

```
<div class="visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
```

2. For PC, following div can be used:

`<div class="hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">`

This is the probably duplicate question : [How can I add a different menu to the mobile version of my bootstrap theme in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270816/how-can-i-add-a-different-menu-to-the-mobile-version-of-my-bootstrap-theme-in-wo)